# Backbone model collection with nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, express, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

Would like to know if anybody used Backbone model, collection in nodejs . My app is totally  dependent on API and would like to use Backbone in current setup.

If anybody knows existing example please share. 
I'm also open for other solutions.

Comment: found this from a google search https://blog.andyet.com/2011/02/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/ backbone wasn't designed with backend in mind... So I'd suggest looking for some alternatives designed for nodejs

Comment: Came across a list of ORM https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-nodejs#database. Need to give it a try